How can enable passing idToken to the underlying apiService in kubeAPI?
My kubeAPI is using OIDC and I've enabled username and group claims.
I created a Kubernetes APIService  under KubeAPI aggregation. I need to decode the idToken and use its data. but KubeAPI only sends limited headers to the API Service:
  'x-forwarded-for': 'x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y',
  'x-forwarded-host': '10.42.0.183:3000',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-scheme': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-uri': '/apis/myapi/v1alpha1/namespaces/1707237939748/tickets',
  'x-real-ip': 'z.z.z.z',
  'x-remote-group': 'owner, system:authenticated',
  'x-remote-user': 'demo@example.org'

Is it possible to tell the KubeAPI to send the original idToken to the APIService?

For the guy (s) who sends close requests because of clarification. Please don't push a button when you have not enough information.

why did you use APIService and not a CRD?

@Thomas CRD only supports CRUD, I need more than CRUD.
